# Issue with WordPress native theme customizer function and jquery ui tabs

Tags: customization

So I am using the customizer in my theme which have tabs in the page utilizing jQuery UI Tabs.  When I load up the customizer, it would the sidebar accordion would be sluggish and the preview page would duplicate the content and the tabs would not render correctly.

This is very strange and it does not produce this issue when you just go to the page on its own ( not in the customizer preview ).  I am also not seeing any errors from my browser console in terms of JS script.  So to test, I disabled the jQuery tabs and everything works in preview customizer again...So it is somehow related to that but I just don't know what.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is indeed a bug.  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23225